# Django forms: get the value of a forms.CharField as a date

Tags: python, django, forms, date, callback

I have a form that has a CharField input for an european date.

I need to transform it to a date python object.

Is there a way to let the form care about it, in the validation? some callback?

I don't want to do it in the view when there's the form processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `clean_FOO` hook is for which populates the `cleaned_data` dict.

```
class MyFrom(..):
    field = forms....

    def clean_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data.get('field')
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(data)
        except Exception:
             raise forms.ValidationError("That ain't no time!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just DateField instead?

Comment: that can be an alternative, but i was searching a general way to approach that problems